# Styling php in a woocommerce action hook

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields

I am trying to add custom fields to the my-account page in Woocommerce using an action hook.  Here is the page with the custom fields loading correctly:

https://blendismoothies.com/my-account/

Here is the code:

```
    add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 20 );

add_action( 'woocommerce_account_dashboard', 'account_custom_area', 1 );

    function account_custom_area () {
            $blendiclubtitle = the_field('blendi_club_title', 'option') ;
            $blendiclubcontent = the_field('blendi_club_content', 'option') ;
            echo "<h2>" . $blendiclubtitle . "</h2>";
            echo "<p class='blendi_club_content'>" . $blendiclubcontent . "</p>";

    };
```

The problem is with the styling - the h2 & p tags are below the content - how do I get the html to wrap around the php?

I hope this makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

use get_field() function.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 20 );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_account_dashboard', 'account_custom_area', 1 );
    function account_custom_area () {
             $blendiclubtitle = get_field( "blendi_club_title", $post->ID );
             $blendiclubcontent = get_field('blendi_club_content', $post->ID) ;
            echo "<h2>" . $blendiclubtitle . "</h2>";
            echo "<p class='blendi_club_content'>" . $blendiclubcontent . "</p>";

    };
```

Comment: Thank you Shital - 'option' is needed as the custom field is on the options page - by changing '$post->ID' to 'option' the <h2> tag worked but the p tag with the class was still being pushed out.  Eventually I changed the p tag to a div and that worked so all is well that ends well :-).  I will post the full solution at the end.  Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

please try the code as follow:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 20 );

add_action( 'woocommerce_account_dashboard', 'account_custom_area', 1 );

function account_custom_area () {
        $blendiclubtitle = the_field('blendi_club_title', 'option') ;
        $blendiclubcontent = the_field('blendi_club_content', 'option') ;
        echo '<h2>' . $blendiclubtitle . '</h2>';
        echo '<p class="blendi_club_content">' . $blendiclubcontent . '</p>';

};
```

Comment: I tried this but it was the same result - the <h2> & <p> tags are below the content instead of surrounding them.  It is really strange... and frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Muhammad & Shital - this ended up sorting out the issue.  The ACF wysiwyg custom field outputs a p tag so changing the p tag to a div sorted out that issue.  Using 'get_field' instead of 'the_field' sorted out the issue with the h2 tag.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 20 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_account_dashboard', 'account_custom_area', 1 );
function account_custom_area () {
         $blendiclubtitle = get_field( 'blendi_club_title', 'option' );
         $blendiclubcontent = get_field('blendi_club_content', 'option') ;
        echo "<h2>" . $blendiclubtitle . "</h2>";
        echo '<div class="blendi_club_content">' . $blendiclubcontent . '</div>';
};
```